# How do I get SQL Server 2005 data stored as windows-1252 as UTF-8?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, encoding

I have a client database with English and French data in windows-1252 encoding. I need to fetch this data as part of an AJAX call and send it in UTF-8 format.

Is there a way I can pass the data through a stored proc to perform this conversion?

My web app cannot be altered to perform this conversion itself.

Comment: Yes, had to migrate over to SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has published a UTF-8 CLR UDT for SQL Server 2008 that can be installed on SQL Server 2005.  See here: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160893.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160893.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

try to cast as nvarchar
or even better use nvarchar columns